# dsPIC30F 10 Bit ADC Module. Meaning of the SAMP bit

Tags: adc, pic

The documentation (https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70064e.pdf) is saying about the `SAMP` bit in the ADCON1 register the following:

```
 SAMP: A/D Sample Enable bit
 1 = At least one A/D sample/hold amplifier is sampling
 0 = A/D sample/hold amplifiers are holding
```

This explanation looks to be simple clear. At the same time the diagram for the example 17.16.7 with sequential sampling is showing the following:
[image: Figure 17-20:]

The explanation in the text tells that sampling starts and happens while another channel is converting. This sounds reasonable from the overall meaning of the text. But the behavior of the `SAMP` signal on the picture above does not follow this concept.

It looks like more appropriate definition would be:

```
 1 = All A/D sample/hold amplifier are sampling
```

Does anybody have experience to confirm this?

For me the function of this bit is an additional condition for triggering the conversion. If the value of `SAMP` is not 1, the conversion will not start even if the condition for `SSRC` is met.

Comment: If the sampling for all amplifieres is complete the SAMP bit is 0.